Why is setInterval method not showing the images animation?
function Animate(){ 
    var image=["Spiral0.png","Spiral1.png","Spiral2.png"]; 
    var i=0;
    setInterval(Timer,100); //This will call the Timer function - units are milliseconds
    
    function Timer(){ 
    document.getElementById("imageDisplay").src="image[i]";
    if (i==2){i=0;}
    else{i++;}
}

I am trying to animate 3 images at a location on the webpage reserved by the id 'imageDisplay'. The animation has to display 3 images in a loop. The images change after each 1/10 seconds.

You set the source to the literal string image[i] - remove the quotes.
